# WordPress deleted post are still showing

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I have set up a new blog in my website. But now i am facing a problem. I have deleted all dummy post that I posted to check while creating it locally. But now I see those deleted post are still showing in my front end but not back-end. I have deleted them form trash too. Even i have used cache killer but no one help.

Could anyone help me to fix this issue please? I would be glad.

Comment: yes used cache killer but it's showing a php error. Can you tell me some good cache plugin that remove cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a catch you have in your wordpress , your posts have been deleted.

It's better to check your plugin settings or you can deactivate the catch plugin , also you can use `WP Super catch` instead (my suggestion).

Comment: WP Super catch remove cache too? I thought it's just create cache to load faster.

Comment: @Tuhin No, that plugin makes catch for your wp but i think this plugin is  better that your plugin. You have to first delete your existing plugin, and then install the plugin i said.

Answer (score 0):

Tuhin,

It almost certainly is caching. It can occur in several locations.

Start by opening your website in a private or incognito window, or simply a browser you don't normally use. It may be that the content is cached in your browser, in which case most people aren't seeing whatever you see.

Now, you used cache killer, so presumably it isn't on your machine (although I would double check that with a new browser or incognito window), but rather on the server. In this case, the question boils down to, what kind of caching is happening on the server side? Are you using Super Cache, W3TC, a CDN, Cloudflare, Batcache, or anything else that might be caching content on the server? Also, have you logged into the database (with phpMyAdmin for example) to double check that your posts were deleted correctly?

In order of what I think is most likely....

1) Your browser is caching things anyway, depsite cache killer

2) Your server is caching things, either with a plugin or a third party service like a CDN

3) Your database settings are off and something is getting "lost in translation"

Option 3 is extremely unlikely... but still worth double checking, if nothing else seems to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Just chiming in because CloudFlare was mentioned here...

CloudFlare only [caches static content](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-What-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content-) by default, unless the user sets a PageRule to have us extend the caching to things like html or php, so this is most likely an issue with another CDN or caching plugin you have enabled.[enter link description here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-)

Answer (score 0):

I use WPsuper cache and after deleting the Cache found the problems was still there. I had to manually update the actual post page and after doing that the problem was resolved .

Good Luck